# Simplifying an exponential expression.

Tags: exponential-function, calculator

maybe this is a stupid question but I have the following expression:

$ 10^{-18}(e^{50,9702078⋅0,75}) = 10^{-18}(4⋅10^{16}) $

How would I go about simplifying the big exponent on the left to what's on the right? With the use of a calculator.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is it $$50.9702078 \cdot 0.75=\ln(4)+16\ln(10)$$?

Comment: by a numerical approach it seems to be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First calculate $50.9702078 \times 0.75 = 38.22765585$. Now there should be a button on your calculator called $e^x$ or something similar. Depending on your calculator, you may have to hit SHIFT $+ \ln$ to use this function.

$$e^{38.22765585} \approx 4.0000000039 \times 10^{16}.$$

Comment: There is the ln button on my calculator and above it it says e^x but when I type in 38.22865585 and press it, I get 3.6435592229.....thanks for all your help guys, I feel so stupid for not knowing how to do this on a calculator. Can't see a shift button though.

Comment: Ah, so you've found the $\ln$ button. You're halfway there. :) The "shift" button might have a different name, like "2nd", and it's usually in the top left corner.

Comment: If you still can't find it, what is the make of your calculator?

Comment: I think I got it! Found the 2ndF button, when I type in the number, press 2ndF and then ln, I get : 4. 16  So, the number on the right will always represent 10 to the power?

Comment: Super! Yes, the $16$ is probably in a superscript and represents $10^{16}$. (You can test this out by doing something like $1,000,000 \times 1,000,000$ and see what happens.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats what I needed to find out, gosh I feel so stupid for not knowing how to operate a calculator : )

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it figured out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't simplify it, the equality ${\rm e}^{50,9702078⋅0,75} = 4⋅10^{16}$ is valid only approximately (check it by taking the natural logarithm in both sides: $50,9702078⋅0,75 = \ln 4 + 16 \ln 10$).